# Retorno em XML PHP - Origem FORM

Tags: php, wordpress, formulário

Estou precisando dar um retorno para este form:

```
    <form action="http://www.guiabp.com.br/staging/" >
      <input name="chave_portal" value="portalteste-0" />
      <input name="codigo_cliente" value="0" />
      <input name="nome" value="XY" />
      <input name="cnpj_cpf" value="x" />
      <input name="endereco" value="Rua X, 01" />
      <input name="bairro" value="Y" />
      <input name="cidade" value="Z" />
      <input name="uf" value="H" />
      <input name="site" value="www.site.com" />
      <input name="email" value="e@site.com" />
      <input name="fone" value="99 9999.9999" />
      <input name="url_xml" value="http://www.site.com/arquivo.xml" />
    </form>
```

Porém o formato de retorno é um XML no formato abaixo:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <root>
         <chave_portal>chave-do-portal</chave_portal>
         <codigo_cliente>1</codigo_cliente>
         <status>Ativo</status>
     </root>
```

Estou gerando o XML sem problemas utilizando o simpleXML:

```
    $retorno =  new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><root/>');
    $retorno->chave_portal = $_REQUEST['chave_portal'];
    $retorno->codigo_cliente = $user;
    $retorno->status = 'Ativo';

     return $retorno->asXML(INTEGRADOR_DIR.'/vista/xml/registro_'.$user.'_vista.xml');
```

Vamos ao ponto. Quando o FORM atinge o endereço ele passa por um redirecionamento para que eu possa pegar funções básicas da plataforma WP. O problema é que o resultado do form está saindo em HTML e não em XML. Olhem o exemplo abaixo:

```
     [Content]
     O Resultado da solicitação vinda do Portal não é um arquivo XML válido: 

     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->  
     <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->  
     <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->  
     <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]--> 
     <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="pt-BR"> <!--<![endif]--> 
     <head>
     <title>Guia Bom de PreÃ§o | Guia BP | AnÃºncios GrÃ¡tis no Guia BP</title>
     <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
     <link rel="pingback" href="http://www.guiabp.com.br/staging/xmlrpc.php" />
```

Se tiverem dúvidas é só questionar. OBRIGADO!

Comment: A função que deveria gerar o XML está sendo executada quando vc envia o form? Coloque o código que deveria gerar a resposta correta pro navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você quer colocar o header de XML, se não o PHP retorna HTML por padrão.

`header('Content-type: application/xml');`

Mais sobre a função [`header`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php)